# How do I send email to an array of email fetched from database with other data

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I have been having  problem using phpmailer to send bulk emails, no problem with a single email though.

here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from $to",$conn) or die("list 
            selected  ($to) does not exist ".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{           
    $email[] = $row['email'];           
    $student[] = $row['name'];
}

foreach ($email as $val => $uemail) {
    $email = $uemail;
    $students= $student[$val] ;

    require("class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

    try {
           $mail->AddReplyTo('info@bratim.com', 'My Name');
           $mail->AddAddress("$email", "$student");
           $mail->SetFrom('info@me.com', 'MyName');
           $mail->AddReplyTo('info@me.com', 'My nameg');
           $mail->Subject = "$sub";

           $mail->MsgHTML("Dear $student<br> $msg <br>
             <img src=\"$path\"> <p>

             $host_upper
            ______________________________________________________
            THIS IS AN AUTOMATED RESPONSE. 
            ***DO NOT RESPOND TO THIS EMAIL****

             ");
            $mail->AddAttachment("$path2");      // attachment

          $mail->Send();
          echo "Message Sent OK to $email  </p>\n";
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    } 
}
```

Any help, suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you assign `$student[$val]` to `$students` inside the foreach but then you assign
the array `$student` to your phpmailer object:

```
$mail->AddAddress("$email", "$student");
```

shouldn't it be

```
 $mail->AddAddress("$email", "$students");
```

other than that is a bad pratice to instantiate a new mailer object for each email you have to send, you should just cicle on the dynamic variables like `AddAddress` and keep all the other outside to avoid overload , and remember to clear the variables that will change, like the `AddAddress`, like this:

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$result = mysql_query("select * from $to",$conn) or die("list selected  ($to) does not exist ".mysql_error());

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $email[] = $row['email'];

        $student[] = $row['name'];
    }

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
try {
            $mail->AddReplyTo('info@bratim.com', 'My Name');
            $mail->SetFrom('info@me.com', 'MyName');
            $mail->AddReplyTo('info@me.com', 'My nameg');
            $mail->Subject = "$sub";
            $mail->AddAttachment("$path2"); 
            foreach ($email as $val => $uemail) {
                $email = $uemail;
                $students= $student[$val] ;

                $mail->AddAddress("$email", "$students");
                $mail->MsgHTML("Dear $student<br> $msg <br>
                <img src=\"$path\"> <p>

             $host_upper
            ______________________________________________________
            THIS IS AN AUTOMATED RESPONSE. 
            ***DO NOT RESPOND TO THIS EMAIL****

             ");
              $mail->Send();
              $mail->ClearAddresses();
            echo "Message Sent OK to $email  </p>\n";
              }
            } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
           } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
             } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send the mail inside the while loop:

```
<?php
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

$result = mysql_query('SELECT `email`, `student`, `data1` FROM `students` ORDER BY `email` ASC;');

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    $current_mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $current_mail->AddReplyTo('info@bratim.com', 'My Name');
    // ....
    $current_mail->Send();
    unset($current_mail);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I was not sensible enough. It's perfect now